# The nonfix operator in SML

Tags: sml

I read the grammar of `SML` and I found out that beside `infix` and `infixr` it also contains `nonfix`. I tried to find some basic examples but it seems that no one uses it. Also tried to find some previous threads about that operator but there are none.

What is the idea behind `nonfix`? Why it seems like no one uses it?

Answer (score 3):

`nonfix` turns an infix operator into a "regular" function on tuples. For example `*` is a function of type `int * int -> int`, but can't be called as e.g. `* (2,3)`. If for some reason you wanted to do that, you could do the following:

```
nonfix *
```

and then `* (2,3)` will evaluate to 6.

Unfortunately, as an annoying side effect, you can no longer use `2 * 3`.

The reason why it doesn't seem to be heavily used is that if I wanted to use `*` as a regular function, I could just use `op`: For example, `op * (2,3)` evaluates to 6. The annoyance of not being able to later on use `*` as an infix operator outweighs the advantage of not having to type `op`.

Comment: Note that it is scoped, though, so the drawback isn't that bad. The only time I ever used `nonfix` was when I wanted to use `mod` as a variable name throughout a certain structure.